# CodeBlocks Help: How to Compile created file

Tags: codeblocks

so I am new to this community and this is my very first question hope someone can help me! :)) I've started to download this so called code blocks IDE for me to code.. so far so good when I am about to run my program, it was compiling main.c (the pre-created file when you create a new project) not the file I was working on. Hope someone helps me..More Power!

PS: I am using codeblocks v16.01

Comment: Probably you should go to youtube, google or whatever to find kickstarter. (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fbG_HrmyAc)  SO is kinda different place. We solve problems, not configure your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatically generated code::blocks projects have their own "hello world" source file in them. What you probably want to do take this main.c file out of the project and then add your file to the project. Or to copy and paste your entire code to substitute main.c content.